# Hamcrest closeTo not working in RestAssured.body()

Tags: groovy, rest-assured, hamcrest, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a test that I cannot get the syntax correctly:

```
@Test
void statsTest() {
    given().queryParam("param", "ball")
            .when().get()
            .then().body("total", is(closeTo(10.0, 0.1*10.0))));
}
```

However, the test keeps failing even though the condition is met:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path total doesn't match.
Expected: is a numeric value within <1.0> of <10.0>
Actual: 10
```

I've never had a problem with types before in this setup of `RestAssured` and `Hamcrest`. For example, a test of the sort: `body("total", greaterThan(9))` works fine, which means that there is some type casting under the hood.

I've looked through the docs and cannot find a way to cast the value of `body("total")` to a numerical value.
so I suspect that this is a bug or I'm not understanding something here.

Here's the JSON response. I had to clip it to make is short. Hope this works.

```
{
 "stats": {
 "totalHits": 1,
 "searchEngineTimeInMillis": 83,
 "searchEngineRoundTripTimeInMillis": 87,
 "searchProcessingTimeInMillis": 101
},
 "products": {
    "id": "total",
    "displayName": "Documents",
    "ball": 10}
}
```

Comment: Please post your JSON response and I can try simulating

Comment: @WilfredClement I've added the JSON response, a trimmed version. Let me know you have problems with it.

Comment: Possibly the value of `total` in response JSON is integer where are comparison is being made to float?

Comment: @SudhirR ok. Any idea how to cast the response to a double?

Comment: @Shejo284 instead of comparing with a float range, why don't you compare to an int range. `.then().body("total", allOf(greaterThanOrEqualTo(1), lessThanOrEqualTo(10)));`

Comment: @SudhirR Thanks. Never thought of that approach.

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The key value pair corresponding to key: "total" in your response seems to be of integer type. So it needs to be checked for bounds with integer based bounds (1,10). So instead of using the `closeTo` matcher, you can use the following matcher.

```
allOf(greaterThanOrEqualTo(1), lessThanOrEqualTo(10)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This thought was to check the bounds on both sides of the `10`, so I need to also check the range `[10, 20]`. Check out my solution above :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've put together another approach that solves the problem but with a slightly different approach. Much thanks to those who populate the web with their code samples. The following assumes you already have set the base `URI` and `PATH`. You can add a path deeper in the response by using the `get("/path...")`. This answer assumes a `JSON` type response.

```
 private static Response getResponse(String paramName, String paramValue) {
    return given().queryParam(paramName, paramValue)
            .when().get();
}

 public static String getJsonValue(String jsonPath, String paramName, String paramValue) {
    Response response          = getResponse(paramName, paramValue);
    //response.getBody().prettyPrint();
    JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
    return jsonPathEvaluator.get(jsonPath).toString();
}
```

You can simply print the return value and cast it to the type you need.
The test then looks like this:

```
 public static void checkIfNumberCloseToValue(String jsonPath,
                                             String paramName,
                                             String paramValue,
                                             Double error,
                                             Double expected) {
    Double value = Double.valueOf(Utils.getJsonValue(jsonPath, paramName, paramValue));
    double range = expected * error;
    assertThat(value, closeTo(expected, range));
}
```